# I want to loop through the dataset and insert data in required positions, then select all rows from temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

currently I am inserting ALL Non Played items into temporary table and then inserting ALL Played items. Instead of this , I want to loop through the dataset and insert where ever i Want, then select all rows from temp table.

```
DECLARE @LEADWONDetail TABLE
(  
  SeqNo [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  Constituencyid INT,
  leadwoncode INT,
  [Status] NVARCHAR(100),
  DistName NVARCHAR(500),
  ConstName NVARCHAR(300),
  MandalName NVARCHAR(300),
  VillageName NVARCHAR(500),
  CandName NVARCHAR(500),
  Party NVARCHAR(200),
  Updatedtimestamp DATETIME
)

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_WB WHERE constid = @SlNo) = 0 AND @SlNo IS NOT  NULL)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_WB 
    SELECT @SlNo
END


INSERT INTO @LEADWONDetail
SELECT A.Const_code AS CONST_CODE, A.Lead_WonCode,
(SELECT
 CASE A.Lead_WonCode
   WHEN '1' THEN N'LEAD'
   WHEN '100' THEN N'WON'
 END) AS [STATUS],R.English as DistrictName,OD.English as ConstName,D.English AS MandalName,A.English AS VillageName, B.English AS CANDINAME, C.English AS Party, A.UPDATEDDATETIME AS [DATETIME]
from tbl_ConstituencyMaster as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_CandidateMaster B ON A.Lead_CandiCode = B.Cand_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_PartyMaster C ON B.PartyCode = C.PartyCode 
join tbl_DistrictMaster D on A.Dist_Code=D.Dist_Code 
join tbl_regionmaster R on a.reg_code=R.reg_code
join tbl_olddistrictMaster od on a.Old_dist_code=od.old_dist_code
AND A.STATECODE = @STATECODE and A.Lead_WonCode = 100 and A.Phase= 1 and R.English in ('ADILABAD','BHADRADRI  KOTHAGUDEM','JAGTIAL','JANGAON','JAYASHANKAR BHUPALPALLY','JOGULAMBA GADWALA','KAMAREDDY','KARIMNAGAR','KHAMMAM','KUMURAMBHEEM','MAHABUBABAD','MANCHERIAL','MEDAK','MEDCHAL','NAGARKURNOOL')
and A.Const_code not in (select distinct ConstId from tbl_WB)
ORDER BY A.UPDATEDDATETIME DESC

INSERT INTO @LEADWONDetail
SELECT A.Const_code AS CONST_CODE, A.Lead_WonCode,
(SELECT
 CASE A.Lead_WonCode
   WHEN '1' THEN N'LEAD'
   WHEN '100' THEN N'WON'
 END) AS [STATUS],R.English as DistrictName,OD.English as ConstName,D.English AS MandalName,A.English AS VillageName, B.English AS CANDINAME, C.English AS Party, A.UPDATEDDATETIME AS [DATETIME]
from tbl_ConstituencyMaster as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_CandidateMaster B ON A.Lead_CandiCode = B.Cand_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_PartyMaster C ON B.PartyCode = C.PartyCode 
join tbl_DistrictMaster D on A.Dist_Code=D.Dist_Code 
join tbl_regionmaster R on a.reg_code=R.reg_code
join tbl_olddistrictMaster od on a.Old_dist_code=od.old_dist_code
AND A.STATECODE = @STATECODE and A.Lead_WonCode = 100 and A.Phase= 1 and R.English in ('ADILABAD','BHADRADRI  KOTHAGUDEM','JAGTIAL','JANGAON','JAYASHANKAR BHUPALPALLY','JOGULAMBA GADWALA','KAMAREDDY','KARIMNAGAR','KHAMMAM','KUMURAMBHEEM','MAHABUBABAD','MANCHERIAL','MEDAK','MEDCHAL','NAGARKURNOOL')
and A.Const_code in (select distinct ConstId from tbl_WB)
ORDER BY A.UPDATEDDATETIME DESC

select * from @LEADWONDetail
```

create table tbl_WB(id int identity(1,1), ConstId INT)

In the executed result present top row is required in 3rd position.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Why do you think you want to use a loop here? I can't make heads or tails of your requirement with so little detail. You might take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas on improving this question.

Answer (score 2):

Without an ORDER BY on the final SELECT, there is no way to enforce the order of the returned results.

The idea that you can INSERT the rows at a specific position and have them returned that way without an ORDER BY is a fallacy.